# formatting python output file in such a way that columns can be accessed later

Tags: python, file-io, output, xls, multiple-columns

In the program I am working on I am reading in data from a .xls filethat looks like this

```
2012-SEP-27     04:35:00        0.035173        0.019666        0.001566        -0.002356       0.028054  0.009819        -9999.000000    0.036353        0.021943        0.003582        -0.0006520.025411 0.009548        -9999.000000    0.035703        0.019268        0.003582        -0.0005340.040426 0.010700        -9999.000000    56.904729       95.722267       7.827207
```

braking it into columns doing some screening of the numbers (this includes grouping certain columns together into 'filters') and then trying to write it back to another .xls file. 
I can write it to a file fine and the output file *looks* the same as the input file, but when I try to access separate columns I either can't (it sees the whole thing as a column) or I can only access it character by character.

I've tried formatting the output a number of ways including:

```
AA = ('{0}     {1}     {2}     {3}     {4}     {5}     {6}     {7}     {8}     {9}     {10}    {11}    {12}    {13}    {14}    {15}    {16}    {17}    {18}    {19}    {20}    {21}    {22}    {23}    {24}    {25}'.format(date, time, filter1[0], filter1[1], filter1[2], filter2[0], filter2[1], filter2[2], filter3[0], filter3[1], filter3[2], filter4[0], filter4[1], filter4[2], filter5[0], filter5[1], filter5[2], filter6[0], filter6[1], filter6[2], filter7[0], filter7[1], filter7[2], LZA, SZA, LAM) + '\n')

AA = [date, time, float(filter1[0]), float(filter1[1]), float(filter1[2]), filter2[0], filter2[1], filter2[2], filter3[0], filter3[1], filter3[2], filter4[0], filter4[1], filter4[2], filter5[0], filter5[1], filter5[2], filter6[0], filter6[1],filter6[2], filter7[0], filter7[1],filter7[2],LZA, SZA, LAM]


AA = [(date, time, filter1[0], filter1[1], filter1[2], filter2[0], filter2[1], filter2[2], filter3[0], filter3[1], filter3[2], filter4[0], filter4[1], filter4[2], filter5[0], filter5[1], filter5[2], filter6[0], filter6[1], filter6[2], filter7[0], filter7[1], filter7[2], LZA, SZA, LAM)]
```

I'm looking for some general help on writing data into a file in such a way that it is accessible by columns, the code I'm working on is hard to explain concisely so general examples are fine. I am new to python and appreciate your help and patience

edit

```
                writer = csv.writer(outputfile, delimiter = '\t')
                row = [date, time]
                row.extend(map(float, filter1))
                for filter in (filter2, filter3, filter4, filter5, filter6, filter7):
                        row.extend(filter)
                row.extend([LZA, SZA, LAM])
                writer.writerow(row)
```

gives me an output that looks like

```
2012-SEP-27     04:35:00        -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -.0      56.904729       95.722267       "7.827207
"
2012-SEP-27     04:39:00        -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 0.0      -9999.0 56.007862       96.708467       "1.784808
"
2012-SEP-27     04:43:00        0.036885        0.038065        0.047741        0.021099        0.0      0.035384        0.034978        0.045806        0.019952        0.013064        0.021955
"
2012-SEP-27     04:47:00        0.038996        0.039075        0.04026 0.020357        0.012688 .036156 0.033027        0.011406        0.011693        0.011979        -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 5
"
2012-SEP-27     04:51:00        -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 0.019505        0.016133        0.018253 146     0.043547        0.012732        0.014486        0.015731        -9999.0 -9999.0 -9999.0 5
"
```

I am trying to access each column using

```
from __future__ import division
import csv
v = open("Pt_2_Test_Data.csv", 'wb') 

with open("outputfile.csv", 'rb') as w:
        reader = csv.reader(w, delimiter = '\t', quotechar = '|')

        for row in w:
                columns = row.split(',')
                date = columns[0]
                time = columns[1]
```

print date will give me the dates, however anything other then columns[0] gives this error

```
    time = columns[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: Have you considered installing Pandas? I use it very frequently for tabular data, in conjunction with the iPython HTML notebook, and it has proven useful for slicing and dicing data. It also provides a few simple functions (e.g. `.to_csv('filename.csv')`) for easy writing of data to CSV format. Buzz me if you'd like help getting started with it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `csv` module and write *tab* delimited values:

```
import csv

with open('outputfile.csv', 'wb') as outputfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outputfile, delimiter='\t')
    row = [date, time]
    row.extend(map(float, filter2))
    for filter in (filter2, filter3, filter4, filter5, filter6, filter7):
        row.extend(filter)
    row.extend([LZA, SZA, LAM])
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Your input file most likely used tab-delimited columns as well, not multiple spaces.

Comment: how would I get it to iterate for each row? I tried adding "for row in w:" (where w = the data file) before the last line but it printed everything out character by character

Comment: Everything beyond the `writer =` line should really be done per row of course; your old code presumably handled things per line of data from the `w` file? It all comes down to you creating a list of columns to pass to `writer.writerow()` for each line in the output file.

Comment: got it, I had stupidly placed the "with open(.....)" line inside the loop so it was getting written over everytime. thanks again

Comment: so now if I want to access a column of data in another body of code (so from outputfile.csv) how would I do that?

Comment: again, when I look at the file it looks like it's formatted correctly, but when I try to access it by columns in another code using line or row.split("\t") I can't.

Comment: Hrm, I thought I responded already. Mea Culpa. Use `csv.reader()` to read you `output.csv` file again.

Comment: However, I would expect using `.split('\t')` should at least work as well. What does `repr(line)` tell you is in the line? Are there `\t` tabs in there when printed as a representation?

Comment: I'm still getting that anything outside of column 0 is out of bounds and I've tried splitting each row by tab, comma, and space. Any ideas?

Comment: Without seeing your output, I cannot help you at all.

Comment: Perhaps you need to make your new problem a *separate*, new question? Comments are hardly the place to solve your new situation. Without seeing how you applied my advice and what output your code produces, it is impossible for me to say what is going wrong.